# Keepalive across multiple fetch commands in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, keep-alive

Our NodeJS application is basically a proxy: it accepts incoming HTTP GET requests from the client A and makes an upstream request to a backend HTTP server B, mapping the data it receives from B to a form suitable for A. Each client request results in a single request to the server B.

In order to maximize performance we'd like to keep the TCP connection to B alive between successive client requests. So if clients A, X, Y and Z all hit our app inside say 10s we'd like to proxy all 4 requests back to B within a single TCP connection.

How can we re-use the same TCP connection (or fetch command) across multiple incoming client requests?

We are using Node 12 and the latest ExpressJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure [an HTTP agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) with `keepAlive: true` and share it across multiple requests so that the agent will reuse TCP connections across multiple requests. If you really want only one connection, you can use `maxSockets: 1` option, but it's better to have more connections to prevent an inflight request from blocking other requests.

Also, [agentkeepalive package](https://github.com/node-modules/agentkeepalive) works as a good drop-in replacement of the HTTP agent from the Node.js standard library, and has a nice README about how to use it.